# getClosestPoint from the mouse-cursor position to first object that hits of the raycast (maya mel script)

Tags: raycasting, mel, closest-points, maya-api

researching for getting a worldpoint from the mouse-cursor position to first object that hits of the raycast. maybe an api func getClosestPoint or rayIntersect can do that job ?if so how? (thank you)

Answer (score 4):

I've found this piece of code, but I'm not exactly sure who wrote it. Anyway, this might be what you're looking for.

```
import maya.OpenMaya as om
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui
import maya.cmds as cmds

ctx = 'myCtx'

def onPress():
    vpX, vpY, _ = cmds.draggerContext(ctx, query=True, anchorPoint=True)
    print(vpX, vpY)

    pos = om.MPoint()
    dir = om.MVector()
    hitpoint = om.MFloatPoint()
    omui.M3dView().active3dView().viewToWorld(int(vpX), int(vpY), pos, dir)
    pos2 = om.MFloatPoint(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z)
    for mesh in cmds.ls(type='mesh'):
        selectionList = om.MSelectionList()
        selectionList.add(mesh)
        dagPath = om.MDagPath()
        selectionList.getDagPath(0, dagPath)
        fnMesh = om.MFnMesh(dagPath)
        intersection = fnMesh.closestIntersection(
        om.MFloatPoint(pos2),
        om.MFloatVector(dir),
        None,
        None,
        False,
        om.MSpace.kWorld,
        99999,
        False,
        None,
        hitpoint,
        None,
        None,
        None,
        None,
        None)
        if intersection:
            x = hitpoint.x
            y = hitpoint.y
            z = hitpoint.z
            cmds.spaceLocator(p=(x,y,z))


if cmds.draggerContext(ctx, exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI(ctx)
cmds.draggerContext(ctx, pressCommand=onPress, name=ctx, cursor='crossHair')
cmds.setToolTo(ctx)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in either MEL or python using the [autoPlace](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/autoPlace.html) command with the useMouse flag set to true.

```
float $pos[] = `autoPlace -um`;
```

It will fire a ray from the mouse cursor to the [live surface](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-EBF1E652-4DDD-423F-B42E-3BF85AE46A5D-htm.html) 
Use the [makeLive](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/makeLive.html) command to make a surface live in a script.

You could write a tool context so that when you enter it, the selected surface becomes live, then you click on it and do something with the result (like place a locator), then deselect the object and makeLive again to reset the grid to be live.